# Why does python socket server always send "None" while printing a value at the same time?

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

im setting up a local network game however when i attempt to send a packet size for unpicking a dictionary i keep getting `None` returned

heres my server (stripped down to the not working portion)

```
player1 = { # players 2-4 are the exact name but renamed
    "id":1,
    "x": 50,
    "y": 50,
    "alive": True,
    "joined": False
}
def client(con, player_data):
    global player1, player2, player3, player4
    player = player_data
    print(player)

    all_players = (player1, player2, player3, player4)
    msgsize = str(sys.getsizeof(all_players))
    print(msgsize.encode())
    con.send(msgsize.encode())
```

ootput of the prints

```
{'id': 1, 'x': 50, 'y': 50, 'alive': True, 'joined': False}
72
```

my client

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "100.115.92.197"
        self.port = port
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        
    def connect(self):
        self.client.connect(self.addr)

    def recv(self):
        message_size = self.client.recv(1000).decode()
        print(message_size)
```

clients output

```
None
```

ive tried struct and sys now

Comment: How are you invoking the client? Show that code too. It's in there somewhere. For example, if you do `net = Network(...) ... print(net.recv())` then it's going to print what the `recv` method returns, which is `None`.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  That means the *exact* code to produce the problem when copied and run with **no changes**.

Comment: Also, `sys.getsizeof()` is not the function to get the size of the player list.  That returns the memory size of the Python object itself.

Comment: im trying to return the memory footprint so i know how much to accept, the client is being initiated in a second file with the connect command being run on initiation

Comment: The "memory footprint" of a python object is unrelated to the bytes sent.  compute the bytes to send and call `len()` on it.  `sys.getsizeof(b'x')` (a single byte) returns 34.  `len(b'x')` returns 1.

Comment: thats not my problem in the first place, for some reason its not sending the value period, but thanks for the heads up

Comment: And which part of the code is supposed to send the value? I don't see it.

Comment: its the `con.send` at the end of the first block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was doing `con.send` instead of `con.sendall`, i solved my issue.